# is it possible to extract smart data into a file type?

Tags: windows

Is there any tool available that will extract the smart data attributes and there values onto file type like a word file or a text file ? I currently am using Disk Checkup, it is giving me the information I required, however am I looking to put the smart data attributes information straight onto a text file.

Comment: I guess you know that the data is of little use?

Answer (score 2):

[GSmartControl](http://gsmartcontrol.berlios.de/home/index.php/en/Home) can do this. Using the GUI, you can find the device name (e.g. `/dev/csmi0,0`). Afterwards, using the device name, you can get the attributes like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\GSmartControl\smartctl.exe" -A /dev/csmi0,0
```

Depending on where you installed to, you might have to adjust the path.

To get the output in a file, you simply need to redirect it:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\GSmartControl\smartctl.exe" -A /dev/csmi0,0 > smart.txt
```